Correlate results from NetStat, Quser, WinSta to return both the Foreign (IP) Address and the username or session ID
I'm trying to map a specific user's SessionID (989) with the Foreign Address (172.xx.xxx.xx) but totally unsuccessful. Is it impossible to correlate the two?
NetStat provides:
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
but there's nothing to correlate the results with a username or sessionid

Are you ultimately looking to get the remote IP address for RDP sessions?  I've had success using quser.exe and Windows event log 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational' ID 1149.  Can join on user and TimeCreated = logon time to get Source Network Address from the event entry

Are you referring to something like, Get-Process -Id 989 -IncludeUsername? Where are you gettingthe SessionID from?

Yes, I've had some success with Quser but basing it on the TimeCreated may not accurately reflect the correct user logon. I have a third party web server that's logging the data.
I can get the Users SessionID from Quser but mapping that to the actual Remote (IP) Address appears to be the real challenge. I've manage to get some good results, after trying over 350 Power Shell scripts but the results don't always reflect a consistent location from which I can parse the user's info. I should mention that the logon port is 443
